Angular ngb-datepicker close() when both dates are selected
I have implemented ng-bootstrap date range component
<input
name="datepicker"
ngbDatepicker
#datepicker="ngbDatepicker"
[autoClose]="'inside'"
(dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event)"/>

<input
  name="dpFromDate"
  type="text"
  #dpFromDate
  (input)="fromDate = validateInput(fromDate, dpFromDate.value)"
  (focus)="onTouch()"
/>
<input
  name="dpToDate"
  #dpToDate
  (input)="toDate = validateInput(toDate, dpToDate.value)"
  (focus)="onTouch()"
/>

And
  onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
  this.fromDate = date;
} else if (!this.fromDate || !this.toDate) {
  const selectedDate = this.fromDate || this.toDate;
  if (date.before(selectedDate)) {
    this.fromDate = date;
    this.toDate = selectedDate;
  } else {
    this.fromDate = selectedDate;
    this.toDate = date;
  }
} else {
  this.toDate = null;
  this.fromDate = date;
}

}
How to close popper window when both dates are selected?
I have tried like this:
// Close the datepicker if both fromDate and toDate are selected
if (this.fromDate && this.toDate) {
  this.datePicker.close(); 
}

But I get error: Property datePicker does not exist on type DateRangeInputComponent

Can you add information what version of angular and what version of bootstrap are you using?

@Jivopis Angular: 17.3.12, bootstrap 5.3.3 and @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap 16.0.0

Solved:
<input
name="datepicker"
ngbDatepicker
#datepicker="ngbDatepicker"
[autoClose]="'false'"
(dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event, datepicker)"/>

and
 onDateSelection(date: NgbDate, datepicker: NgbInputDatepicker) {
    // Close the datepicker if both fromDate and toDate are selected
    if (this.fromDate && this.toDate) {
      datepicker.close();
    }
  }


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
